# div vs fieldset elements -- legend validation

Tags: html

I need some advice from the HTML guru's out there.

Semantically I feel FIELDSET best fits a form that contains a list of fields for a user to fill in and submit.  However, without a embedded LEGEND element, the page fails HTML 5 validation.  We are using an H1 tag to title the form and don't need a LEGEND.

We can add an empty LEGEND element to the FIELDSET and that fixes the validation issue.  However is there something better to use for this situation (other than just DIV)?

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this, because the latest HTML5 spec says that the legend element is optional. I tried it without a legend, and it passes the W3 validator. Where is it failing validation for you? See: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-fieldset-element

Comment: The 6 Aug 2011 Editor's Draft for HTML5 says, "The name of the group is given by the first legend element that is a child of the fieldset element, if any."  This would indicate to me that @adimauro is correct, and that the legend element is optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I often find myself using a form fieldset without a legend and have come up with an elegant and screenreader friendly solution, while retaining the correct document outline and HTML5 validation.
See the following code:

```
<section>
  <h2 id="legend-heading">
     Inputfield buttons
  </h2>

  <form method="post" action="" name="inputfield-form">
    <fieldset aria-labelledby="legend-heading">
      <legend class="hide"></legend>
      ...
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
```

The class "hide" on the legend element has the rule "display:none" assigned which hides the content from view. Also, screen readers skip content that has display:none assigned. By setting the aria-labelledby attibute on the fieldset we tell screen readers to use the element with the corresponding id ([multiple id's are allowed here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute)). By using the h2 (or any other heading element) we get a proper document outline and we end up with DRY code that's accessible, valid and SEO friendly.

Comment: Modern browsers support `<legend hidden>`.

Answer (score 21):

A fieldset without a legend should indeed be fine as a means of grouping form inputs. Don't be afraid to use divs or form elements, though, especially if you intend to reuse this code somewhere where you do want something like a legend. This is because fieldsets **with** legends should be avoided unless you are using them to group a single set of checkboxes or radio buttons.

Why? Some screen readers  assume that field sets will only be used that way and are optimized for that use case, causing the screen reader to announce the legend on every single input in the list, making it annoyingly verbose to tab through the inputs and decreasing the accessibility of the form. This is one of those rare cases where you can reduce the usability of your HTML by making it too semantically rich.

For a lengthier explanation, see this old (but still relevant) link: https://web.archive.org/web/20130922062411/http://www.rnib.org.uk/professionals/webaccessibility/wacblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?id=40

Comment: That's pretty interesting, thanks for sharing. This provides another reason to keep legend text concise and meaningful as well, although this does seem like a flawed method for screen readers to relay the content. I'm also not convinced about the last statement in your first paragraph, but this is a very useful contribution nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks, Wesley. Though it may seem strange that screen readers adopt this behavior (and just about all the major ones do), there's a real reason for it. Prior to many of the developments in ARIA (much of which is not yet implemented in browsers or readers), there was no other way to get this behavior in the use cases where it WOULD be desirable. In contrast, the behavior that most people expect of it pretty much duplicates the semantic use of heading tags (h1-h6), except h tags also help clarify the input group's  semantic relationship to the whole document rather than just to the form itself.

Comment: @BrunoTorquato, isn't this a problem with the screen readers that they should fix? Why should we adapt to their error instead of being correct and letting them adapt to our correctness?

Comment: @Pacerier, because it's the users who suffer because of this, not the makers of the screen readers

Comment: @JBarnes, and screen reader makers will suffer when their users suffer.

Comment: @Pacerier, not exactly. There's nothing incorrect about what screen readers have done. For the vast majority of what `<fieldset>` is actually used for in the wild (those simple cases I mentioned), it's fairly helpful and appropriate behavior.
I would argue that there is a lot more harm done by overzealous web devs (like myself) who love to pat themselves on the back for coming up with overly clever ways of making code "elegant" and "semantically accurate". We get so wrapped up in opinions about how our code should look, that we forget that we are ultimately building experiences for people.

Answer (score 7):

You're right in that `FIELDSET` fits the bill.

`DIV` is used too often, IMO, for catch-all situations where the designer doesn't really know what else to use for a container, much as `TABLE` used to be so often used for layout (mostly out of laziness).

I don't see a problem with an empty `LEGEND` element, but consider replacing your `H1` with a styled `LEGEND` for maximum semantic yumminess.

Comment: Or even consider setting `display:none` on the `legend` (assuming it's semantically relevant to leave the h1). Not all semantic information needs to be presented to the user directly.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Good thinking, though styling the `LEGEND` would still be preferable if it describes the `FIELDSET` like a title. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Unfortunately LEGEND tags are a pain to style, and have limited positioning possibilities.  See here for some info: http://morten.dk/blog/fieldset-legend-behave